# FInding the derivative of $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$ at the origin using chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as  $f(0,0)=0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and   $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$ otherwise.
Then we know that $f$ is differentiable at the origin and the derivative is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$. As far as I know this is calculated from the first principle. But I was wondering if one can solve it using chain rule. Two obvious approaches that I can think of:

1. Compose the function $(x,y)\to x^2+y^2$ with the function $z\to z \sin(\frac{1}{z})$. But $z\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is not differentiable at $z=0$, so we can not apply chain rule here.
2. Compose the function $(x,y)\to \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with $z\to z^2\sin(\frac{1}{z^2})$. But in this case $(x,y)\to \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

This got me wondering if there are cleverly chosen functions that we can compose and apply chain rule to get the answer. Or is it possible to prove that no such functions exist?
Thanks for your time.